# Ruby on Rails 2.3, form_tag submitted to Rails controller, JS function not called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-2

Current setup: Ruby on Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.8.7 (don't ask...we're working on it).

form_tag helper is used in a Bootstrap modal to call action in Rails controller. Here's the view (.haml)

```
- form_tag({:action => 'update_logins'},
{:method => :post, :multipart => true, :id => 'upload_form', :target => 'upload_target', :class=>'form-horizontal' })
```

The controller action is properly called, but I am returning a call to a Javascript function, and despite numerous attempts, it is not calling the function, but instead appears to be rendering text. Even a simple render statement in the controller doesn't work: `render :js => "alert('hello');"`

I have a feeling this has to do with how the request header doesn't seem to accept javascript:

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

The response header indicates Javascript: `Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8`

And the response is received properly: `alert('hello');`

But no success in getting it to actually call any functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SLIM/HAML for templating engine.
check if you are generating a `<form>` tag in your HTML

you can try replacing

```
- form_tag({:action => 'update_logins'},{:method => :post, :multipart => true, :id => 'upload_form', :target => 'upload_target', :class=>'form-horizontal' })
```

to

```
= form_tag({:action => 'update_logins'},{:method => :post, :multipart => true, :id => 'upload_form', :target => 'upload_target', :class=>'form-horizontal' })
```

this way, it will create a `<form>` in your html.

Comment: There is already a `<form>` in the HTML. When I do change it to this to try it out, it unfortunately breaks things and the modal won't even come up anymore: `ActionView::TemplateError (form_tag outputs directly to the Haml template. Disregard its return value and use the - operator, or use capture_haml to get the value as a String.`